# Inserting rows to SQL Server database with multiple loops

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm gathering a list of users and their information that I would like to store in a database table. I have this database set up in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. The primary key of the database is set to auto-incrementing. I need the loop to end when there are no more users in the list. I have two valid users in the test account however what I currently have only inserts a single user. Would I be better off to use a `sqlDataAdapter`?

```
List<User> result = ims.ListUsers(req).ListUsersResult.Users;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString);

for (int i = 1; i < result.Count(); i++)
{
    foreach (User user in result.Where(x => x.UserName.Contains('@')))
    {
        string sql = @"INSERT INTO UserInfo (UserID, UserName) VALUES (@UserID, @UserName)";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", i);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", user.UserName);

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: since PK UserID is auto-increase, why you insert it with value? the second time you run this will generate exception.

Comment: I don't understand why you have the `for` loop.  It seems that the `foreach` is doing everything you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you need the outer `for-loop` to create the ID since you should not set the primary key column manually. It will increment automatically. You should also  always close a connection when you're finished

Here is the complete code:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO UserInfo (UserName) VALUES (@UserName)";
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach(var user in result.Where(x => x.UserName.Contains('@')))
    {
        // you don't need to set the UserID when you've set made it an Identity column
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", user.UserName);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first answer is incorrect, this will not help until there are two loops and he is updating auto-incrementing field.

Comment: This did the trick for me. I appreciate the help. Just one of those Fridays! Thanks again!

Comment: @SergeyS: Yes, you're right. The for loop is just redundant. Edited my answer.

Comment: Also remove UserId part from the INSERT construction

Comment: I did that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace:

```
for (int i = 1; i < result.Count(); i++)
```

With:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have 2 loops.  You need to remove the first for loop and instead increment a int variable each time you execute through your foreach()

You are adding multiple users with the same UserID

```
int userID = 1

foreach (User user in result.Where(x => x.UserName.Contains('@')))
{
    // your code

    userID++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to update auto-incrementing field, it will count automatically by SQL server. Try this code:

```
        List<User> result = ims.ListUsers(req).ListUsersResult.Users;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString);

        foreach (User user in result.Where(x => x.UserName.Contains('@')))
        {
            string sql = @"INSERT INTO UserInfo (UserName) VALUES (@UserName)";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", user.UserName);
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```